# How to replace a substring with a regex pattern using regex in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string `"word ***.** word"`. And I want to replace the `'***.**'` with `'[\d][\d][\d].[\d]+'`. Unable to do it using regex as it's giving key error for `'\d'`.
My code is:

```
text = 'word ***.** word'
updated_text = re.sub(re.compile(r'\b\*\*\*\b', re.I), '[\d][\d][\d]', text)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 1039, in parse_template
this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
KeyError: '\\d'
```

I know that my code is not correct. But I can't think of any different way. Didn't find anything in the community blogs, as well.

Comment: Use a raw string and double escape the backslash `updated_text = re.sub(re.compile(r'\b\*\*\*\b', re.I),  r'[\\d][\\d][\\d]', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import re

text = 'word ***.** word'
updated_text = re.sub(re.compile(r'\*', re.I), r'[\\d]', text)
print(updated_text)
```

Comment: Yes, it did. I had tried double slashes but missed the `r`. So, it wasn't working. Thanks.